# Easiest frameworks to implement Java REST web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, restlet

What are the best frameworks for implementing both client and server REST frameworks in Java?  I've been struggling a little to find an easy to use solution.

**Update**: Both Jersey and Restlet seem like good options.  We'll probably use Restlet but we'll experiment with both.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71068/a-few-possible-duplicate-questions-about-java-rest-what-should-we-do

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) sounds like it should provide what you're looking for:

- Support for client and server (in a relatively symmetric api)
- Smart url binding
- mime type understanding (given accepted mime types, it will ask your resources for their representation in that type)
- Supports JAX-RS annotations (just like Jersey)

Comment: +1 I've had excellent results with Restlet in a large production application.

Answer (score 24):

[Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) is really easy for both.  To write web services, you use annotations:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
    @GET
    // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media
    // type "text/plain"
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String helloWorld() {
        // Return some cliched textual content
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

For a client:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/helloworld");
String s = webResource.get(String.class);
System.out.println(s); // prints Hello World
```

Comment: +1 for Jersey, the JAX-RS (JSR 311) Reference Implementation. Also have a look at http://java.sun.com/javaone/2009/articles/gen_restful.jsp

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.1/docs/) too.

Answer (score 3):

Restlet also support annotations in its 2.0 version, both on the client and server-side. The JAX-RS API is also supported as an extension.

Here is a simple example for server-side:

```
public class HelloWorldResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get
    public String represent() {
        return "hello, world";
    }

}
```

On the client-side:

```
// Outputting the content of a Web page  
new ClientResource("http://www.restlet.org").get().write(System.out);
```

For further documentation, [check this page](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/).

Comment: Restlet looks promising, but the documentation is disappointing.

Comment: The "Restlet in Action" book will be published by Manning in September 2012. It has a comprehensive coverage. Next, we will improve the tutorial and Javadocs (versions 2.2 and 3.0)

Answer (score 2):

There's JBoss' new [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/) library.  It appears to be under rapid development since its initial launch.  I've no idea if it's any good; it's on my 'check it out' list.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally but some teams that I work with are using Spring 3 MVC.  [REST in Spring 3: @MVC](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/) looks like a good blog post overview.  The RESTful features include "URI Templates", "Content Negotiation", "HTTP Method Conversion", "ETag support" and more.

**Edit**: Also, see this question:  [Can anyone recommend a Java web framework that is based on MVC and supports REST ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069772/can-anyone-recommend-a-java-web-framework-that-is-based-on-mvc-and-supports-rest)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the CXF JAX-RS implementation. For complete list of its features check the [CXF web site for JAX-RS](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html). 
The community behind the project seems to be very active (July 2013). An indication of that is the number of messages per day in the  [CXF mailing lists](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Apache wink, a new framework still in incubation mode, but very mature and high quality.

http://incubator.apache.org/wink/

It implements the JAX-RS specification, it has both client & server framework for REST development. 
Apache is standing behind this project - that's always a good sign (and a good license :-) )

What I love most about this framework is the intuitive integration with Spring, it's very useful if you want your framework to be easily configured and extended.

Comment: BTW, Restlet is also distributed under Apache Public License, in addition with other licensing options (EPL, LGPL 2.1 and 3.0, CDDL) :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Xydra Restless is not longer maintained +++ If your are using Goolge AppEngine before they release a "reserve instance" feature, you might consider [Xydra Restless](https://github.com/alanma/Xydra) which has few features but loads fast.

Answer (score -1):

My favourite is Spring [MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html), you have support for both, client and server side... And you have Android support too =)

For example, you can see a example of Spring Android [here](http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=163&lang=en)

Comment: The Android link is to Javier's own blog, that seems not online anymore.