# How to develop a simple database based project

Tags: database, web-services, web-applications, architecture, software-design

I want to start an information provider service. It works this way:
Some employees will find the information needed and fill a database manually.
Users will request data they need on their client side apps on their own platforms. Some of the project specifications is as follows: 1) Data that will go between database server and clients is really small(Suppose some ordinary images). 2) The client side apps don't need to be kept updated. Once the user of app clicks update button(for example) the app will request the server to send required information. 3)It's important to run client side apps on several platforms like: windows, windows phone, android, ios,... 4) Database doesn't need to be vary fast or vary big.

## Note: And It's important to note that I'm not expert and I have some limitations. I know java and html, css, javascript. But I think those are enough for this project. (Am I right?)

So I decided to design this development architecture:
1)Using hibernate and provide a layer for server which stands above hibernate and is used to do database-specific tasks. This layer provides some protocols for client side apps to communicate with server. It enables me to change database later without changing client side apps. 2)Using PhoneGap which is a framework that uses html, css, javascript and produces apps for many platforms.
I really appreciate any suggestion, comment,... Thanks!

Comment: This question isn't really on-topic for Stack Overflow, it's for specific programming questions, not general advice or opinions on which stack is best for your project

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way in Java world would be spring boot. Basically you can configure whole application: datasource, orm, persistance layer and rest services just by adding proper annotations. There are many examples of how to do it. Basically with current implementation of spring jpa and web services you can bind mapped resources to rest services. Also current JPA can generate SQL for you using DAO method name. SO e.g. findPersonByName will generate proper sql for you (of course you need to map your db model in entities but this is also simply done with annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a sufficient tech stack to accomplish your goal.  You will have to decide how much logic to implement server-side vs app-side.

Pick a java framework for providing an API so that you can expose a restful API to your apps.
Here are a couple of comparisons from stack overflow:

[Which is the best Java REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965543/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api)

[Easiest frameworks to implement Java REST web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495813/easiest-frameworks-to-implement-java-rest-web-services)

Answer (score -2):

no! for database you need server side scripting language, like php or perl, java-script is client side and will only work on browser. i recommend first learning mysql database, just the basics how to create Db, table, insert and fetch. then some PHP. i think these will set the ground for your project. '

for development environment : download XAAMP! it comes complete with Sql-database base and PHP.

Comment: java is a server side language.  Hibernate is the persistence framework to accomplish this.