# Rest based WebServices in JAVA

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, jax-rs

What is best method to implement ReST based Web Services in Java. Should I go for JAX-RS implementations. Or should I go for Spring MVC or directly via Servlets? Well what is the actual difference with these?

Comment: Have a look at the following similar questions:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495813/easiest-frameworks-to-implement-java-rest-web-services and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069772/can-anyone-recommend-a-java-web-framework-that-is-based-on-mvc-and-supports-rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed the REST services in Spring MVC as well as Jersey.
If you only need to create REST api use JERSEY and if your project is more then REST Api you can use Spring MVC . Some useful links are as follows -

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

http://jersey.java.net/

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use  JAX-RS, it requires to write less for the same result.

Spring MVC:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/convert", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ConversionController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String jsonToXml(@RequestBody String jsonString) throws JSONException {
        //method body
    }
}
```

JAX-RS:

```
@Path("/venue")
@Consumes(Const.FORMAT_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
@Produces(Const.FORMAT_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
public class ConversionController 
{
    @POST
    public Venue addVenueToDatastore(Venue aVenue) {
         //method body
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use JAX-RS implementation. I recommend [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [Resteasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy). Spring MVC is a bit verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I use [VRaptor MVC framework](http://vraptor.caelum.com.br/en/) in order to build RESTful and service oriented applications in a simpler way, just like I was writing common web applications... Might worth taking a look at the [ten minutes guide](http://vraptor.caelum.com.br/documentation/vraptor3-ten-minutes-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) for Web Service. Here is some [example](http://playframework.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/web-services-using-play/) how to do it.